# Multiselect dinâmico com bootstrap

Tags: jquery-ui-multiselect

boa tarde.

estou com um grande problema. tenho um combo de select dinâmico que é a seguinte ordem:

1. Pais
2. UF
3. Cidade
4. Bairro

Essas informações são carregadas do MYSQL. Considerando que seja uma select dinâmico, preciso que o campo bairro se torne um "multiselect". Para selecionar vários bairros de uma vez.

meu código é este(combo.js):

```
    jQuery(document).ready(
function() 
{});

$(pais).load('localizacoes.php?tipo=pais');

$(pais).change(
    function() {
        if($(this).val() == 0) {
            alert('Você precisa informar um PAÍS!');
            $(this).focus();
        } else {
            $(estado).load('localizacoes.php?tipo=estado&pais=' + $(this).val());
        }
    }
);

$(estado).change(
    function() {
        if($(this).val() == 0) {
            alert('Você precisa informar o ESTADO!');
            $(this).focus();
        } else {        
            $(cidade).load('localizacoes.php?tipo=cidade&estado=' + $(this).val());
        }
    }
);

$(cidade).change(
    function() {
        if($(this).val() == 0) {
            alert('Você precisa informar a CIDADE!');
            $(this).focus();
        } else {        
            $(bairro).load('localizacoes.php?tipo=bairro&cidade=' + escape($(this).val()));
        }
    }
);  

$(bairro).change(
    function() {
        if($(this).val() == 0) {
            alert('Você precisa informar o BAIRRO!');
            $(this).focus();
        } else {        
            return true;
        }
    }
);}
```

**AQUI MEU TESTE.PHP**

```
    <!-- Include the plugin's CSS and JS: -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="dist/js/bootstrap-multiselect.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/css/bootstrap-multiselect.css" type="text/css"/>
</head>
<body>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#bairro').multiselect({
                maxHeight: 10000
            });
        });
    </script>

    <form action="" method="post">
        <h1>Localizações</h1>
        <label><span>País:</span>
            <select name="pais" id="pais"></select>
        </label>
        <label><span>Estado:</span>
            <select name="estado" id="estado"><option value="0">--Primeiro o País--</option></select>
        </label>
        <label><span>Cidade:</span>
            <select name="cidade" id="cidade"><option value="0">--Primeiro o Estado--</option></select>
        </label>
        <label><span>Bairro:</span>
            <select name="bairro" id="bairro">
                <option multiple="multiple" name="multiselect[]">--Primeiro a Cidade--</option></select>
        </label>
        <br />
        <label><input type="submit" value="Procurar"  />

    </form>


</body>
```

Comment: Seria algo assim: http://jsfiddle.net/filadown/pL4hg76b/11/ ? Você pode também preenche-los e depois usar o `.multiselect('rebuild');`

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/StephenEdmondson/TR49m/4/

Você pode fazer algo parecido com isso!